# node-pg-migrate not able to run migrations from config defined with .env variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, database-migration

I have a workspace where I want to use the npm package `node-pg-migrations` to handle database migrations for all of my databases.

`.env` file variables:

```
MULLIGAN_DB_USER=my_user
MULLIGAN_DB_PASSWORD=my_password
MULLIGAN_DB_HOST=localhost
MULLIGAN_DB_PORT=6969
MULLIGAN_DB_NAME=mulligan
```

`workspace folder structure`:

```
.
├── index.js
├── package.json
└── projects
    └── mulligan
        ├── config.js
        ├── index.js
        └── migrations
            └── 001_initial-migration.js
```

The `index.js` file in my root is empty. 
My command `mulligan-migration` runs the command:

```bash
node-pg-migrate $@ -c ./projects/mulligan/index.js -m ./projects/mulligan/migrations
```

When I run the command `pnpm run mulligan-migration -- up` I get the following errormessage:

```bash
pnpm run mulligan-migration -- up

> db-migrations@1.0.0 mulligan-migration /home/mads/workspace/db-migrations
> node-pg-migrate $@ -c ./projects/mulligan/config.js -m ./projects/mulligan/migrations "--" "up"

could not connect to postgres: Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string
```

When console logging the config from my `config.js` file inside `./projects/mulligan/index.js`

```js
import { config as dotenvConfig } from "dotenv";
dotenvConfig();
import pkg from "pg";
const { Client } = pkg;
import config from "./config.js";

console.log("config", config);

const client = new Client(config);
```

The output is just `undefined` across the board from my `./projects/mulligan/config.js` file.

```js
const config = {
  user: process.env.MULLIGAN_DB_USER,
  password: process.env.MULLIGAN_DB_PASSWORD,
  host: process.env.MULLIGAN_DB_HOST,
  port: process.env.MULLIGAN_DB_PORT,
  database: process.env.MULLIGAN_DB_NAME,
};

export default config;
```

Am I over complicating this setup? Is it even possible to do this? It would be nice to have a project that contained all of my migration logic for all other projects.

`project dependencies`:

```
"dotenv": "^16.4.5",
"node-pg-migrate": "^6.2.2",
"pg": "^8.11.3"
```